# Deleting a file

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket, sys, os
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.title("File Deleter v1.0")
root.config(bg='black')
root.resizable(0, 0)

text = Text()
text3 = Text()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.config(bg="black")
frame.pack(pady=10, padx=5)

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.config(bg="black")
frame1.pack(pady=10, padx=5)


text.config(width=35, height=1, bg="black", fg="white")
text.pack(padx=5)

def button1():
    try:
        x = text.get("1.0", END)
        os.remove(x)
    except WindowsError:
        text3.insert(END, "File Not Found... Try Again\n")      

def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", END)  

c = Button(frame1, text="Clear", width=10, height=2, command=clear)
c.config(fg="white", bg="black")
c.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text3.config(width=35, height=15, bg="black", fg="white")
text3.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text3.yview)
text3.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

w = Label(frame, text="Delete A File")
w.config(bg='black', fg='white')
w.pack(side=TOP, padx=5)


b = Button(frame1, text="Enter", width=10, height=2, command=button1)
b.config(fg="white", bg="black")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

I dont get why the delete code is not working, I get a "File not Found" even if the file exist.

Comment: "File not found" is hardly the only thing that could go wrong when deleting a file. What does the exception actually report? (Look at the `strerror` field.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe gnibbler is on track with whitespace being the problem.  The Text Widget gives you endline characters \n.  Try adding a .strip() to the end of your text.get or you can use an Entry widget as opposed to a Text Widget since your Text widget is only one line anways.

```
x = text.get('1.0', END).strip()
```

Answer (score 3):

When I run this code on Linux and place a breakpoint in `button1()`, I see that the value of `x` includes a trailing newline character. That means the `os.remove()` call won't work, because the filename I typed in didn't actually contain a newline. If I remove the trailing newline, the code works.

Comment: correct: the text widget is guaranteed to always have a trailing newline. The original code should be "x=text.get("1.0", "end-1c")"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps x is not what you think it is, just a guess but maybe there a some whitespace there or somthing, try this to check

```
def button1():
    try:
        x = text.get("1.0", END)
        print repr(x)
        os.remove(x)
    except WindowsError, e:
        print e
        text3.insert(END, "File Not Found... Try Again\n")
```